# Why does RestTemplate consume excessive amounts of memory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

## Question

Why does Spring's RestTemplate use an excessive amount of heap (particularly the `G1 Old Generation`) when sending a file.

## Context

We observed the [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) to consume excessive amounts of memory when sending files via `POST` requests. We used Spring's [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) as comparison and it behaves completely sane.

We created a [demo project on github](https://github.com/Trinova/RestTemplate-vs-WebClient) which contains the full code. The important parts are the following snippets:

```java
private void sendFileAsOctetStream(File file) {
    final RequestEntity<FileSystemResource> request = RequestEntity.post(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/file"))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(new FileSystemResource(file));
    restTemplate.exchange(request, void.class);
}
```

and

```java
private void sendFileAsOctetStream(File file) {
    webClient.post()
            .uri("/file")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new FileSystemResource(file)))
            .exchange()
            .block();
}
```

We observed the memory usage with `jconsole` when sending a 550MB file with both the implementations (left is `WebClient`, right is `RestTemplate`. The `WebClient` cosumes a couple of MegaBytes while the `RestTemplate` requires 2.7 GigaByte:

[image]

1. An initial manual GC to clean the old generation
2. The request
3. A manual GC (only for the `RestTemplate`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to the default `RestTemplate` which simply uses an unconfigured `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` for the creation of the requests.

The mentioned requst factory has a flag `bufferRequestBody` which by default is set to `true`, which leads to very high memory consumption when sending large requests.

From the javadoc of `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory#setBufferRequestBody()`:

> Indicate whether this request factory should buffer the request body internally.
> Default is true. **When sending large amounts of data via POST or PUT, it is recommended to change this property to false, so as not to run out of memory**. This will result in a ClientHttpRequest that either streams directly to the underlying HttpURLConnection (if the Content-Length is known in advance), or that will use "Chunked transfer encoding" (if the Content-Length is not known in advance).

You can provide your own request factory, when creating the `RestTemplate` by using one of the other overloaded constructors, and setting mentioned flag to `false` on the request factory:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    rf.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    return new RestTemplate(rf);
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Thanks a lot!